# sort in shell using multiple -t

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

I have a file that contains:

```
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:25:01        /index.html

192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:23:00        /index.html

192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      10:29:37        /products.html

192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:22:49        /products.html

192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      10:05:17        /products.html

192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      12:24:24        /products/004.html

192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:09:13        /products/296.html

192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      11:01:20        /products/296.html

192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      12:19:55        /products/560.html
```

I want to, first, sort by IP in number, if same then use the forth one separated by tabs in alphabet
the file name is `access-2014-09-04.log`. I tried `sort -t. -k1,2 -k3,4 -n -t $'\t' -k4 access-2014-09-04.log`

but it tells me `sort: incompatible tabs`.

Comment: Please add an example of desired end result ... It looks like GNU's natural version sorting is what you want ... Try `sort -V access-2014-09-04.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your command into a pipeline with two `sort`s:

```bash
sort -t $'\t' -k4 access-2014-09-04.log | sort -t. -k1,2 -k3,4 -n -s
```

Output:

```
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      12:19:55        /products/560.html
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      10:05:17        /products.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:25:01        /index.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      12:24:24        /products/004.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:09:13        /products/296.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      11:01:20        /products/296.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:23:00        /index.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      10:29:37        /products.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:22:49        /products.html
```

First I sort by your 2nd criterion, the path. Now the list is sorted in path order. Then I sort by the 1st criterion. I add `-s` to make it a stable sort so that the 2nd sorting criterion is not wasted. The result is that if the 1st criterion is different, said 1st criterion will be taken into consideration, but if it's the same, the previous order in the 1st step (ordered by the 1st criterion) is maintained.

By the way, your `-k1,2 -k3,4` does not seem to sort IP address correctly. If you want to simply sort with `.` as the separator, you need to use `-k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4`:

```bash
sort -t $'\t' -k4 access-2014-09-04.log | sort -t. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -n -s
```

The `--debug` option revealed this to me. However I consider the `-V` option to be cleaner than a bunch of `-k`. The `LC_ALL=C` is also nice. For that cleaner solution, please see the second half of [@steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502638/1004020).

Comment: You don't need `-t $'\t'` in the first `sort` since there's no white space in the first 3 fields and `-k4` will sort **starting from** the 4th field so it doesn't matter if there's any white space from there on.

Answer (score 2):

A *numeric* (`-n`) sort on the IP addresses will only consider the first two octets as a "number" - as you can verify using the `--debug` option:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort --debug --stable -t $'\t' -k1,1n access-2014-09-04.log 
sort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>10:25:01>/index.html
_______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>11:23:00>/index.html
_______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>10:29:37>/products.html
_______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>11:22:49>/products.html
_______
192.168.83.173>2014-09-04>10:05:17>/products.html
_______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>12:24:24>/products/004.html
_______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>10:09:13>/products/296.html
_______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>11:01:20>/products/296.html
_______
192.168.83.173>2014-09-04>12:19:55>/products/560.html
_______
```

(I added `--stable` to omit the final whole-line lexical sort just for clarity).

AFAIK, you can't use two different field separators within a single `sort` command - although you can break a key into further subfields using a `KEYDEF` of the form `F.C` where `F` is the actual field number and `C` is a character position within the field. So *in this particular case* where the first two octets are all 7 characters long, you could fake a "dot separated" numeric sort of the first tab separated true field (**don't really do this - it's just meant to illustrate the `F.C` notation and will fail IRL where the octets may be 1,2, or 3 characters long**) using `-k1.1,1.7n -k1.9,1n`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort --debug -t $'\t' -k1.1,1.7n -k1.9,1n -s access-2014-09-04.log 
sort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
192.168.83.173>2014-09-04>10:05:17>/products.html
_______
        ______
192.168.83.173>2014-09-04>12:19:55>/products/560.html
_______
        ______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>10:25:01>/index.html
_______
        _______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>12:24:24>/products/004.html
_______
        _______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>10:09:13>/products/296.html
_______
        _______
192.168.130.175>2014-09-04>11:01:20>/products/296.html
_______
        _______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>11:23:00>/index.html
_______
        _______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>10:29:37>/products.html
_______
        _______
192.168.138.244>2014-09-04>11:22:49>/products.html
_______
        _______
```

I suspect what you actually want is to natural sort the IP by *version* (`-V`) and then sort by name with the default lexical ordering:

```
$ sort -t $'\t' -k1,1V -k4 access-2014-09-04.log 
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      12:19:55        /products/560.html
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      10:05:17        /products.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:25:01        /index.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      12:24:24        /products/004.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:09:13        /products/296.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      11:01:20        /products/296.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:23:00        /index.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      10:29:37        /products.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:22:49        /products.html
```

Specifying stable sort (`-s` / `--stable`) does not seem to be necessary since the remaining fields (date and time) appear to be lexically ordered anyhow. Note that will sort the filename column in your locale's lexical order - add `LC_ALL=C` to force strict byte order.

Comment: Yep a number shouldn’t have more than one decimal point  … That’s why I think.

Comment: You don't need `-t $'\t'` since there's no white space in the first 3 fields and `-k4` will sort **starting from** the 4th field so it doesn't matter if there's any white space from there on.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) with any awk+sort+cut:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ip=$1; gsub(/\./,OFS,ip); print ip, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n -k8 | cut -f5-
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      10:05:17        /products.html
192.168.83.173  2014-09-04      12:19:55        /products/560.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:25:01        /index.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      12:24:24        /products/004.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      10:09:13        /products/296.html
192.168.130.175 2014-09-04      11:01:20        /products/296.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:23:00        /index.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      10:29:37        /products.html
192.168.138.244 2014-09-04      11:22:49        /products.html
```

Comment: Ok, replacing `.` with TAB in the IPs and sorting each octet as a separate field ... nice +1

Comment: @Raffa thanks. It's funny that I've posted 2 answers here and they're both coincidentally using DSU!

Comment: You seem to like DSU and I don’t blame you … In some cases it’s vital as it might be the shortest, most efficient and most understandable solution to bring tough mixed and complex input  into a state where it can be reliably correctly sorted  while it might require lengthy processing otherwise and in other cases it might be the only way.

Comment: @Raffa I mostly lurk over at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) where I maybe post a DSU solution about once every 6 months, 2 in a row here is an anomaly! I do agree that when it is applicable it's usually the best approach for clarity, simplicity, efficiency, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc.